# angular js - getting json data

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am trying to get data from json data so i write this:

```
app.factory('data', function($resource) {
    return $resource('mock/plane_urls.json', {}, {
        getTreeData: { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
    })
})
```

and then using:

```
data.getTreeData.Carriers.Carrier;
```

Where Carriers is the first node in json file. but it doesnt work ;/ I got error

> Error: data.getTreeData.Carriers is undefined

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to reach into the `Carriers` object before it is fetched. Before the data comes back, Carriers is just an empty object.

You could do something like `$scope.carriers = data.getTreeData();` and then in your view have an element with `ng-repeat="carrier in carriers"`

The idea behind $resource is that you get an empty object, so the view renders nothing. When the request is complete, the empty object is replaced and the view is re-rendered with the data automatically.

You could also use the $http service like so and provide a callback function that executes once the data is fetched.

```
$http.get('mock/plane_urls.json').then(function(data){
    carrier = data.Carriers.Carrier
});
```

BUT! should break this into a service and a controller though. Just have the service `getTreeData` return the promise object like so: `return $http.get('mock/plane_urls.json');` and then in your controller call it with then() and provide the callbacks for success and error:

```
getTreeData.then(
    function(data){
        carrier = data.Carriers.Carrier;
    }, 
    function(err){
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    });
```

Comment: I need to get this data in script. Is there another way to fetch it?

Comment: Zhoutuo Yang's approach will work. Also you could use $http object to send your request and provide a callback function that accesses `Carriers.carrier`

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detail on using $http and a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $scope.$watch to watch the value of the data.getTreeData.
When new data comes in, the callback will be called, then, you can get your data you want.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope